# How to enter a non static method from a static one

Tags: java, object, methods, static, non-static

```
CollegeTester.java:10: error: non-static method getCommand() cannot be referenced from a static context
        getCommand();//goes to command
    ^
```

How would I enter this method. Making it `public static void` only causes more problems

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeTester
{   
    public String name;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getCommand();//goes to command
    }

    //Ask user for a command
    public void getCommand()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really learn a bit more about OOP (here in particular the difference between static and instance methods) before asking any more questions on this site.

Comment: Besides Njol's advice, i should also separate the CollegeTester class from the main class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method (method name()) cannot be referenced from a static context. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282093/non-static-method-method-name-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-wh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it as in main :

```
CollegeTester c = new CollegeTester();
c.getCommand();
```

Comment: do i put CollegeTester c = new CollegeTester() in the main or class?

Answer (score 0):

`getCommand()` is not static so you can not call this in `main()` as `main()` is static.You have create an object and then call `getCommand()`.

Or make `getCommand()` static

This is the way by creating object and calling getCommand()

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class CollegeTester
    {   
    public String name;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
CollegeTester c=new CollegeTester();
        c.getCommand();//goes to command
    }

    //Ask user for a command
    public void getCommand()
    {
        do stuff
    }
```

This is the way of making `getCommand()` static

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeTester
{   
public String name;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    getCommand();//goes to command
}

//Ask user for a command
public static void getCommand()
{
    do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-static methods are **instance methods**, and thus accessed over an instance of the class:

```
new CollegeTest().getCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the CollegeTester class in main method and call the method.

```
new CollegeTester().getCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of CollegeTester :

```
   main(...)
   {
      CollegeTester t = new CollegeTester();
      t.getCommand();
   }
```