# getInteger returns error (android)

Tags: android, tostring

I have a class WinTasks in which i have a method that calls an integer. It happens in the next form.

```
public Item(JSONObject data) throws JSONException {
      number = data.getInt("number");
}
```

Number returns an integer that comes from a server. Now i am trying to call this in another class as i want to display it as a string in my application. For that i try the next thing :

```
int a  = Integer.getInteger(WinTasks.Item.number);
String b = Integer.toString(a);
```

This returns me an error : Non-static field number cannot be referenced from a static context.

Anybody knows how to fix this?
Thanks in advance,
Zakaria

Comment: Define number as static in WinTasks.Item class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method (method name()) cannot be referenced from a static context. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282093/non-static-method-method-name-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-wh)

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks boys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your "number" variable as a static variable like below:

```
static int number;
```

Comment: Will mark as correct, although this logic doesn't fit into to the program i want since the int will change. But this is the correct answer indeed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define number as static Item class :

```
class Item {
    public static int number;
    public Item(JSONObject data) throws JSONException {
        number = data.optInt("number");
    }
}
```